# What are the Advantages of Using OnAsyncPostBackError over Page_Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax, exception

I am currently researching an exception handling architecture for our App.

We will be using `UpdatePanels` extensively and we will also be calling Webservices.

I want to know if there is any real need to implement a `ScriptManager.OnAsyncPostBackError` handler compared to, the `Page_Error` event which seems to catch all exceptions that are thrown in the app.

The only benefits appears to be the possibility to customise error messages, but that can be achieved if you have access to the `Scriptmanager` object itself.

Are there any situations where the `AsynchPostBackError` will catch something the `Page_Error` won't?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncPostBackError event should be catpured when we want to customize exceptions occured during AJAX post back. 
Whereas, Page___Error method handles error occured in the page life cycle even AJAX is not used. 

For more information about AsyncPostBackError, check this:
http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETAJAX/115_Error_Handling_in_ASPNet_Ajax_Applications.aspx

Comment: thanks but I've already read that article. What I wanted to know is if there are any real benefits to using the AsynchPostBack handler as opposed to the Page_Error

Comment: @nialljsmith If the answerer didn't answer the question, why did you mark it as the answer? I'd like to know the answer to this as well.